# Difference between WCF rest and Wcf soap Services

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, soap

Am new to wcf concept.

As Per my understanding, if the service endpoint binding is basicHttpBinding then it is soap service.

And if the endpoint binding is webHttpBinding then it is Rest service.

In short if we can able to retrive result from browser by calling public methods, then it's a rest service..

Please suggest is that correct.

Note: in case services are public accessible

Comment: Why you compare available transfer options to protocol? REST only defines that it should have CRUD operations, access given data by URIs and data should be hypertext (HTML, XML, JSON,...) **it doesn't define protocol** ... SOAP its just protocol ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WCF you can use either the BasicHttpBinding (SOAP 1.1 specification) or the WSHttpBinding (SOAP 1.2 specification) for SOAP web services. Both of these bindings support SOAP messages.

The WebHttpBinding supports HTTP requests, and not SOAP messages. However, a REST service is a lot more than just responding to HTTP requests, it is more about *how* you respond to the HTTP request, e.g., using the HTTP verb (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE) to map onto operations on a resource, so that GET = read, POST = create, PATCH = update, and DELETE = delete. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Wikipedia for the basics.

So a WCF service may use the WebHttpBinding but not be a RESTful service. There is a lot more work involved to create a proper RESTful service. In converse, a RESTful service does not need to use WCF and the WebHttpBinding. I recommend instead using ASP .Net Core and MVC to develop REST APIs. There is a good tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).